# Dirichlet Series Question

Tags: nt.number-theory, dirichlet-series

Consider $a_n$ a real valued sequence and define $D_{1,1,1}(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n^s}$ which converges in some half plane $\Re s =c.$  Define $D_{r,h,k}(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{2\pi i \frac{hrn}{k}} a_n}{n^s}.$

Question:  Suppose $D_{1,1,1}(s)$ has an analytic continuation to a half plane $R$ with a simple pole at $s=c.$  Is is necessiarly true that $D_{r,h,k}(s)$ must have an analytic continuation to $R$ with at most a simple pole at $s=c?$

**EDIT:**   This question was answered by GH in the negative. His response leads me to ask a follow up question.  Does the above statement hold if $a_n\geq 0?$

Comment: I fixed your tags from [number] and [theory] to [nt.number-theory]

Comment: Is there supposed to be an $n$ in the exponential?  The $h$ and $r$ intervene only through their product, so why are they separate indices?  Are you thinking about twisting Dirichlet series that arise in some interesting way - if so, some context would help. 

Comment: Yes there is supposed to be a $n$ in the exponential.  Unfortunately, I have trouble drafting things typo free.

Comment: @Daniel: I answered your question in the negative.

Comment: @GH:  Thanks for the counterexample.  Its such an interesting sequence to choose.  How did you think of it?

Comment: @Daniel: I added a section to my answer where I try to explain how I came up with the example.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A counterexample is provided by $c=1$ and $a_n=\sum_{d\mid n}(-1)^d$.
Indeed,
$$ D_{1,1,1}(s)=(2^{1-s}-1)\zeta(s)^2 $$
has a simple pole at $s=1$, but
$$ D_{1,1,2}(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^na_n}{n^s}=(1-2^{1-s}+2^{1-2s})\zeta(s)^2 $$
has a double pole at $s=1$.

**EDIT:** Daniel asked in a comment how I came up with this sequence, so I try to explain. Vaguely, the original question asks the following: can we create a pole of a Dirichlet series by additive twists? In other words, can the coefficients of a Dirichlet series obey much less cancellation along arithmetic progressions than originally? The answer to this vague reformulation is obviously yes, e.g. there is a lot of cancellation in the formal sum $1+(-1)+1+(-1)+\dots$ but there is no cancellation in its formal subsums $1+1+1+\dots$ and $(-1)+(-1)+(-1)+\dots$. So a natural candidate for creating a pole by additive twists is $\sum_n (-1)^n/n^s$ which can be twisted to $\sum_n 1/n^s$. Indeed, here we create a pole at $s=1$, because the first series equals $(2^{1-s}-1)\zeta(s)$ but the second series equals $\zeta(s)$. Now this does not answer the original question since $(2^{1-s}-1)\zeta(s)$ has no pole at all. We can remedy this by considering $(1-2^{1-s})\zeta(s)^2$ instead, i.e. by convolving the sequence $(-1)^n$ with $1$. This is my final example above: I simply checked that it worked, i.e. it creates a double pole from a single one!

Comment: So I see that this depends on the fact that the sequences can be positive and negative.  Would you know if this type of method would fail for $a_n$ all positive?

Comment: The question with $a_n\geq 0$ is certainly more difficult, I will think about it as time permits. In that case, by Landau's theorem, the original series converges for $\Re s>c$, so the same is true for the twisted series. In particular, any additional pole must lie in $\Re s\leq c$. I suspect that there is no counterexample which grows only polynomially slightly to the left of $c$, but I have no time to work on this now.